# Best Possible algorithm to check if two linked lists are merging at any point? If so, where?

Tags: linked-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linked list interview question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594061/linked-list-interview-question)

This is an interview question for which I don't have an answer.
Given Two lists, You cannot change list and you dont know the length.
Give best possible algorithm to:

1. Check if two lists are merging at any point?
2. If merging, at what point they are merging?
3. If I allow you to change the list how would you modify your algorithm?

Comment: See [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594061/linked-list-interview-question)

Comment: I came across this while searching for a solution. I think it is worth reading for        http://richardhartersworld.com/cri/2008/linkedlist.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that we are talking about simple linked lists and we can safely create a hash table of the list element pointers.

Q1: Iterate to end of both lists,  If the respective last elements are the same, the lists merge at some point.

Complexity - `O(N)`, space complexity - `O(1)`

Q2:

1. Put all elements of one list into a hash table
2. Iterate over 2nd list, probing the hash table for each element of the list.  The first hit (if any) is the merge point, and we have the position in the 2nd list.
3. To get the position in the 1st list, iterate over the first list again looking for the element found in the previous step.

Time complexity - `O(N)`.  Space complexity - `O(N)`

Q3:

1. As Q1, but also reverse the direction of the list pointers.
2. Then iterate the reversed lists looking for the last common element - that is the merge point - and restoring the list to the original order.

Time complexity - `O(N)`.  Space complexity - `O(1)`

Comment: "Put all elements of one list into a hash table" - Merging doesnt necessary mean that the nodes have the same value!! I hope you are using the node->value as the key to index the hash table? Or are you using the address of the nodes?

Comment: @letsc - if a question is vague, I choose to interpret it in a way that makes my solution work :-)

Comment: Q3, are you suggesting reverse(listA), then reverse(listB) ? cuz that doesn't work if they listA and listB are connected. If you reverse listA first, then the common nodes' pointers are already reversed, so that part is lost for listB. listB is messed up with you reverse(listA). How do you reverse both lists at the same time if they are not the same size?

Comment: Here is a full explanation for this question: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-function-to-get-the-intersection-point-of-two-linked-lists/

Answer (score 1):

Number 1: Just iterate both and then check if they end with the same element. Thats O(n) and   it cant be beaten (as it might possibly be the last element that is common, and getting there always takes O(n)).

Comment: But this doesn't indicate which one of the elements is the merge point.

Answer (score 1):

1. Walk those two lists parallel by one element, add each element to Set of visited nodes (can be hash map, or simple set, you only need to check if you visited that node before). At each step check if you visited that node (if yes, then it's merging point), and add it to set of nodes if you visit it first time. Another version (as pointed by @reinier) is to walk only first list, store its nodes in Set and then only check second list against that Set. First approach is faster when your lists merge early, as you don't need to store all nodes from first list. Second is better at worst case, where both list don't merge at all, since it didn't store nodes from second list in Set
2. see 1.
3. Instead of Set, you can try to mark each node, but if you cannot modify structure, then it's not so helpful. You could also try unlink each visited node and link it to some guard node (which you check at each step if you encountered it while traversing). It saves memory for Set if list is long enough.

Comment: 1) There is no need to walk them in parallel. They can be iterated consecutively as well.

Comment: and thinking about this more... for the 2nd list you don't even need to store the elements in the set anymore, speeding up things.

Comment: @reinier You're right. But if they merge early enough, then you don't need to walk through full list. There are pros and cons, which I should highlight in my answer

Comment: @reiner -- if you think of the non-common parts of the two lists as prefixes to the common part, walking in parallel allows you to visit just the longest prefix nodes of each.  If you walk them separately, then you will have to visit the entire list for one and the prefix for the other.  It will potentially use more space, though.

Answer (score -2):

Traverse both the list and have a global variable for finding the number of `NULL` encountered . If they merge at some point there will be only 1 `NULL` else there will be two `NULL`.

Comment: This is wrong every list ends with NULL, so the global will be 2 anyway