# Find the least common parent in a binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, least-common-ancestor

This question might have been asked by a lot of guys but, it is kinda different. We have a binary tree. And you are given two nodes p & q. We have to find the least common parent. But you dont have root node pointer which points to the root. You are provided with two inbuilt functions which are:

1) `BOOL same(node *p, node *q);` -> returns true if the nodes are same or else false.

2) `node* parentNode(node *c);` -> returns a node which is the parent of the current node.

If the node c is actually root then parentNode function will return you with a`NULL` value.
Using the functions we have to find the least common parent of the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming C++:

```
node* leastCommonParent(node *p, node *q)
{
    node *pParent = parentNode(p);
    while(pParent != 0)
    {
        node *qParent = parentNode(q);
        while(qParent != 0)
        {
            if (0 == same(pParent, qParent))
                return pParent;
            qParent = parentNode(qParent);
        }
        pParent = parentNode(pParent);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: A version without explicitly declared variables using recursion follows. I'm sure it can be improved and would probably never use it in production code in the current form.

```
node* qParent(node *p, node *q)
{
    if (p == 0 || q == 0)
        return 0;
    if (same(p, q) == 0)
        return p;
    return qParent(p, q->parent);
}

node* pParent(node *p, node *q)
{
    return qParent(p, q) ? qParent(p, q) : pParent(p->parent, q);
}

node * result = pParent(p, q);
```

Comment: ok.. i will accept the answer but is there anyway to do it without making use of temporary nodes.

Comment: Thanks. The function just uses pointers to the nodes, so no copy of nodes is being made and that's why I'm not entirely sure why temp nodes would be a problem. One might be able to do without the pointers using recursion, depending on the requirements.

Comment: I try to mean u shldn't use extra variables or pointers for saving the address. Reason is that this particular question was asked to friend in the interview. And it was said that he was not supposed to use any temporary pointers or variables.

Answer (score 6):

**Step1:** Using `parentNode` function find the distance `d1` of the node `p` from root. similarly find distance `d2` of node `q` from the root. (say, `d2` comes out ot be greater than `d1`) 
**Step 2:** Move the farther node(whose ever d-value was greater) pointer `d2-d1` steps towards root. 
**Step3:** Simultaneously move pointers `p` and `q` towards root till they point to same node and return that node.

Basically it will be like finding the merge point of two linked-lists. 
 Check the below link:
[Check if two linked lists merge. If so, where?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594061/linked-list-interview-question?lq=1)

Time complexity: O(N)
Your code would look somewhat along the lines:

```
node* LCP(node* p, node *q){
    int d1=0, d2=0;
    for(node* t= p; t; t = parentNode(p), ++d1);
    for(node* t= q; t; t = parentNode(q), ++d2);
    if(d1>d2){
        swap(d1, d2);
        swap(p, q);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<(d2-d1); ++i)
        q = parentNode(q);
    if( same(p, q)){
        return parentNode(p);
    }
    while( !same(p, q)){
        p = parentNode(p);
        q = parentNode(q);
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: This will fail in one case, when `p` is the ancestor of `q`(or even `p==q`), your algo will return `p` . The `least common parent` is `p->parent`. I'm assuming that one is not one's own parent.

Comment: ah! yes, you are right. I've now updated the code to take care of that edge case.