# lca of binary tree of two nodes if those two nodes occur many times

Tags: c++, binary-tree, least-common-ancestor

this is my implementation of  my binary tree (this is not the code for Lca just normal implementation of binary tree just to give a idea how i constructed the binary tree)

```
void insert(int n)
{
create(&root,n);
}
void create(node** temp,int n)
{
if(root==NULL)
{
(*temp)=new node;
(*temp)->data=n;
(*temp)->right=NULL;
(*temp)->left=NULL;
root=*temp;
}
else
{
if((*temp)==NULL)
{
(*temp)=new node;
(*temp)->data=n;
(*temp)->right=NULL;
(*temp)->left=NULL;
}
else
{
char c;
cout<<"enter the direction";
cout<<endl;
cin>>c;
if(c=='l')
create(&((*temp)->left),n);
else
create(&((*temp)->right),n);
}
}
}
```

now my question is how to find lowest common ancestor of two nodes if the two nodes are same in both right subtree and left subtree
for example
[image: lca of 4 and 5 see that 4 and 5 are there in both right sub tree and left sub tree of root(two times ocurred)]

so what should be lowest common ancestor of this

i understood the answer of nick johnson in the below question but i am not understanding how to do the above type of tree

[How to find the lowest common ancestor of two nodes in any binary tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484473/how-to-find-the-lowest-common-ancestor-of-two-nodes-in-any-binary-tree)

Comment: Please start indenting the code you write. It makes life so much easier.

Comment: What's the difference between your question and the one you linked?

Comment: @interjay my question is what is the lca of 4 and 5

Comment: You can find the lca between two specific nodes. The values stored in the nodes are irrelevant.

Comment: in questions like these you are directly given pointers to the nodes, you are not usually asked to find the ancestor given 2 values