# Given two objects, can you find the nearest common ancestor?

Tags: raku

Given two objects is there a simple way in Raku to find the
nearest common ancestor in their tree of inheritence?

There are already some general answers for this:

[How to find nearest common ancestor class of two objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68074665/how-to-find-nearest-common-ancestor-class-of-two-objects)

[Algorithm to find common ancestor of two nodes given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403058/algorithm-to-find-common-ancestor-of-two-nodes-given)

I was wondering if there's an idiomatic solution built-in to Raku
already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```raku
  class A {}
  class B is A {}
  class C is B {}
  class D is B {}
  class E is D {}

  say E.^parents.first: * === D.^parents.any
```

Comment: That's a good start, though in that example I would've said the
"least common ancestor" would be D, even though you could argue
that D is not technically an ancestor of itself:

You can treat an E like a D and you can treat a D like a D, you
don't have to treat both like a B.

Perhaps something like this:

    say E.^parents.map({ .gist }).first({ $_ === D.^mro.map({ .gist }).any });   # (D)

Comment: @JosephBrenner `sub ancestors2 (\class) { class, |class.^parents }; say E.&ancestors2.first: * === D.&ancestors2.any; # (D)`.