# locating lowest common ancestor in AVL tree

Tags: algorithm, avl-tree

I have an AVL tree and 2 keys in it. how do I find the lowest common ancestor (by lowest I mean hight, not value)  with O(logn) complexity? 
I've seen an answer here on stackoverflow, but I admit I didn't exactly understand it. it involved finding the routes from each key to the root and then comparing them. I'm not sure how this meets the complexity requirements

Comment: Why don't you link to that old question then? Anyway, the height of an AVL tree is `O(log n)`, so is the length of the path to the root.

Comment: I know that logn is the height, but how do I compare the 2 routes?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1484810/1971525

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first node you move up and **mark the nodes**. For the second node you move up and look if a node on the path is marked. As soon as you find a marked node you can stop. (And remove the marks by doing the first path again).

If you cannot mark nodes in the tree directly then modify the values contained to include a place where you can mark. If you cannot do this either then add a hashmap that stores which nodes are marked.

This is O(logn) because the tree is O(logn) deep and at worst you walk 3 times to the root.

Also, if you wish you can alternate steps of the two paths instead of first walking the first path completely. (Note that then both paths have to check for marks.) This might be better if you expect the two nodes to have their ancestor somewhat locally. The asymptotic runtime is the same as above.

Comment: Why mark at all? Just walk up, reverse the paths, and walk back on both paths simultaneously until they split.

Comment: That is is possible too and you should add it as an answer. I did not even think of it because it needs dynamic memory (or a clever implementation) to build the lists.

Comment: Also it can not use the possible locality (like the alternating version does). But his algorithm has other advantages i think, he should add it as an answer.

Comment: Actually it can be done in  constant memory. Just do a standard tree traversal. When the two keys are found in different subtrees of the current node, you have found the LCA

Answer (score 0):

A better solution for the AVL tree (balanced binary search tree) is (I have used C pointers like notation)-

1. Let `K1` and `K2` be 2 keys, for which LCA is to be found. Assume `K1 < K2`
2. A pointer `P = root` of tree
3. If `P->key >= K1` and `P->key <= K2` : `return P`
4. Else if `P->key > K1` and `P->key > K2` : `P = P->left`
5. Else `P = P->right`
6. Repeat step 3 to 5

The returned P points to the required LCA.

Note that this approach works only for BST, not any other Binary tree.