# How to compute a least common ancestor algorithm's time complexity?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, time-complexity, least-common-ancestor

I came into an article which talking about the LCA algorithms, the code is simple
http://leetcode.com/2011/07/lowest-common-ancestor-of-a-binary-tree-part-i.html

```
// Return #nodes that matches P or Q in the subtree.
int countMatchesPQ(Node *root, Node *p, Node *q) {
  if (!root) return 0;
  int matches = countMatchesPQ(root->left, p, q) + countMatchesPQ(root->right, p, q);
  if (root == p || root == q)
    return 1 + matches;
  else
    return matches;
}

Node *LCA(Node *root, Node *p, Node *q) {
  if (!root || !p || !q) return NULL;
  if (root == p || root == q) return root;
  int totalMatches = countMatchesPQ(root->left, p, q);
  if (totalMatches == 1)
    return root;
  else if (totalMatches == 2)
    return LCA(root->left, p, q);
  else /* totalMatches == 0 */
    return LCA(root->right, p, q);
}
```

but I was wondering how compute the time complexity of the algorithm,can anyone help me?

Comment: fwiw: Lowest Common Ancestor can also be found in O(1) if you can pre-compute for all nodes (in O(n) time) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_off-line_lowest_common_ancestors_algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The worst case for this algorithm would be if the nodes are sibling leave nodes.

```
Node *LCA(Node *root, Node *p, Node *q)
{
  for root call countMatchesPQ;
  for(root->left_or_right_child) call countMatchesPQ; /* Recursive call */
  for(root->left_or_right_child->left_or_right_child) call countMatchesPQ;
  ...
  for(parent of leave nodes of p and q) call countMatchesPQ;
}
```

`countMatchesPQ` is called for `height of tree times - 1`. Lets call height of tree as `h`.

Now check the complexity of helper function

```
int countMatchesPQ(Node *root, Node *p, Node *q) {
  Search p and q in left sub tree recursively
  Search p and q in right sub tree recursively
}
```

So this is an extensive search and the final complexity is `N` where `N` is the number of nodes in the tree.

Adding both observations, total complexity of the algorithm is

```
O(h * N)
```

If tree is balanced, `h = log N` (RB tree, treap etc)
If tree is unbalanced, in **worse case** `h may be up to N`

So complexity in terms of `N` can be given as

> **For balanced binary tree: O(N logN)**
>   *To be more precise, it is actual h(N + N/2 + N/4...)*
>   *for balanced tree and hence should come 2hN*
>   **For unbalanced binary tree: O(N<sup>2</sup>)**
>   *To be more precise, it is actual h(N + N-1 + N-2...)*
>   *for balanced tree and hence should come h x N x (N+1) / 2*

So the worse case complexity is N<sup>2</sup>

Your algorithm doesn't use any memory. By using some memory to save path, you can improve your algorithm drastically.

Comment: More precisely, h(N + N/2 + N/4...) should be h * logN right?

Comment: @bigpotato For an infinite series (N + N/2 + N/4...), the sum of terms is 2N.

Answer (score 4):

The complexity of [LCA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5000698/1031417) is `O(h)` where `h` is the height of the tree. The upper bound of the tree height is `O(n)`, where `n` denotes the number of vertices/nodes in the tree.

If your tree is balanced, (see [AVL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), [red black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)) the height is order of `log(n)`, consequently the total complexity of the algorithm is `O(log(n))`.

Comment: You counted cost of LCA. But in his implementation, OP traverses the subtree in each call (`h` times) in function countMatchesPQ. So the total complexity should be more than h. Isn't it?

Comment: You are right. That's why we have your answer for :)