# How to implement lowest common ancestor for a binary tree using Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, lowest-common-ancestor

I encountered the following implementation and spent some time, but still can't grasp the idea. Could someone please explain line by line what it is doing? I just don't understand at what point it can decide a node is an ancestor.

Thank you

```
public class Solution {
    public TreeNode lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
        if(root == null || root == p || root == q)  return root;
        TreeNode left = lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, p, q);
        TreeNode right = lowestCommonAncestor(root.right, p, q);
        if(left != null && right != null)   return root;
        return left != null ? left : right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Recursive functions can be really tricky to understand. Drawing them on paper helps.

Comment: The code here is a slightly more compact version of the one in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9046307/2513200

Comment: @Hulk no offence, the difference is completely irrelevant, even for compiler perspective.

Comment: @SauravSahu yes, I agree that it is equivalent. The difference is purely style and comments.

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea behind marking the presence of a number in a tree branch is to use the **non-null** pointer for number *FOUND*, and **null** pointer for *NOTFOUND*.

The call stack winds back once a number (`p` or `q`) is found, or when the `root` is `null`. Later one gives a clear indication of absence of the searched number.

There are four possible scenarios:

1.) Both under one parent.

```
                      root
                      /  \ 
            Leftsubtree  Rightsubtree
                p/q        q/p
```

In this case,  in the below code, a moment would come when this is satisfied `if(left != null && right != null) return root;`

2.) One parent of other.

```
      q/p                     p/q
      /            OR          \ 
Leftsubtree                 Rightsubtree
  p/q                           q/p
```

In this case, this will be satisfied `if(root == null || root == p || root == q)  return root;`

3.) Either of them not present in the tree.
This condition would go **undetected**. As shown in case#2, the function returns immediately without further traversing and looking for its counterpart in the tree below it.

4.) None of them are present in the tree.

First line `if(root == null ... return ;` will be executed for each non-existing child. The final result would be `null` return, as none of the number would ever be found.

---

Line by line code explanation.

```
public TreeNode lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
    if(root == null || root == p || root == q)  return root;

    /* (root == null)  This proves that root is not in the branch of tree of our interest. Returning null would means NOTFOUND.*/
    /* (root == p || root == q) either p or q or both are found. Returning non-null root would means FOUND. */

    /*Check for presence in leftsubtree */
    TreeNode left = lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, p, q);

    /*Check for presence in rightsubtree */
    TreeNode right = lowestCommonAncestor(root.right, p, q);

    /*            root
                  /  \ 
        leftsubtree  Rightsubtree
            p/q        q/p

    */
    if(left != null && right != null)   return root; //both the numbers are found inside tree under root 

    // left or right subtree OR both don't have p or q. Return the overall find result under root.
    return left != null ? left : right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public TreeNode lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
    // root == null (no root no LCA)
    // root == p || root == q (if either p or q is the root then root is LCA)
    if(root == null || root == p || root == q)  return root;
    //get the LCA of p and q in left sub tree
    TreeNode left = lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, p, q);
    //get the LCA of p and q in right sub tree
    TreeNode right = lowestCommonAncestor(root.right, p, q);
    // if one of p or q is in left subtree and another is in the right subtree, 
    //then the root is the LCA
    if(left != null && right != null)   return root;
    // if left is not null, left is LCA, else right is LCA 
    return left != null ? left : right;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484473/how-to-find-the-lowest-common-ancestor-of-two-nodes-in-any-binary-tree

Answer (score 0):

```
if(root == null || root == p || root == q)  return root;
```

if current `root node` is **null** then at current sub_tree there doesnt exist the `common ancestor` of **p** and **q**, so return `null root==null`

and if **p** or **q** equals `root`. I assume *p=root* and here as for **q**, it is either the  `offspring` of **p** or `not offspring` of **p**, **however** which case, **there are no need to travese the sub_tree of p**, for if the former case **p** is ancestor of **q** so just return **p p==root**, else return **p** directly, it dont produce error although in this case **p** is not `ancestor of q`.
 for the statement
    `if(left != null && right != null)   return root;`
 and I will explain it later.

```
    TreeNode left = lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, p, q);
    TreeNode right = lowestCommonAncestor(root.right, p, q);
```

> now there are exist several possible things:
>   **1.** the p and q are all `offspring` of root.left
>   **2.** the p and q are all `offspring` of root.right
>   **3.** these two node one is `offspring` of root.left the other is `offspring` of root.right

---

these two `recursive statement` are used to find the `common ancestor` of *p and q*  (**for 1,2**) 
**else** used to find *p* and *q*  (**for 3**)

---

```
if(left != null && right != null)   return root;
```

this statement is used to process the `corresponding result` of **3**, the p and q exist the `left_subtree and right_suntree` of root, so `ancestor`  is **root**

---

```
 return left != null ? left : right;
```

this statement is used to process `corresponding result` of **1,2**,
**p**and **q** exist same sub_tree either left or right.

Comment: This is the first answer directly addressing `please explain line by line what [this LCA implementation] is doing?`. It could point out explicitly that for "external" use, it _presumes_ both _p_ and_q_ to be in the tree at _root_, while during the "internal"/recursive use, it _relies on_ this not always being the case, belying the _common_ in `lowestCommonAncestor()`. Let _me_ point out that the "solution" presented in the question lacks doc comments as well as in-line comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
TreeNode* lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* p, TreeNode* q) {
    if (root == NULL || root->val == p->val || root->val == q->val ||
        (p->val < root->val && root->val < q->val) ||
        (q->val < root->val && root->val < p->val)) {
        return root;
        }
    else if (root->val < p->val) return lowestCommonAncestor(root-> right, p, q);
    else return lowestCommonAncestor(root->left, p, q);
```

Here is my answer in C++, but should be very similar as long as you switch the '->' to '.' syntax. It's a recursive function where it checks the current leaf with its left and right children and once the first if statement conditions are true, it means it identified the lowest common ancestor because if either of its children are bigger, it means that it is the smallest value.

For example: given 2 as its root and 1 and 4 as its children(left and right respectively), 1 is lower than root, but 4 is not, so 2 is the smallest common denominator. IT would stop at the first run.

If you draw yourself a binary tree and test out each step it will make much more sense.